# How can one make arrows as in the figure below?

Tags: gis

I am very interested in war history and would like to make operation maps by myself. Really appreciate if anyone know how to draw attack arrows as in the figure below. Would be great if a GIS software can do that. Thank you very much.

[image: Ukraine Situation Map]

Answer (score 0):

GIS Programs can do this. I'm unclear if you have pre-existing line data or not, but regardless you can add an arrowhead in 'Symbology'.

If you do not have lines showing the movement you can create them in ArcGIS with 'Create Features'. You will draw where you want the lines to be and can add the arrowhead in the symbology afterwards.

See this post:
https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/show-direction-of-route-with-arrow-symbol-in/td-p/613399